# Use of Do-End Loop in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset as follows and its titled: "RiverPlace-JulyReport-2007.txt”

```
"Price" "Building"  "Floor" "SquareFootage"
------- ----------  ------- ---------------
169.9   "South"     4       369
204     "South"     11      405
205     "South"     9       572
215     "South"     5       559
259.5   "South"     4       716
169.5   "West"      5       425
199     "West"      9       514
205     "West"      6       559
211.8   "West"      7       514
215     "West"      8       559
264     "West"      8       722
397     "West"      10      866
144.95  "East"      2       367
162.5   "East"      3       383
199.5   "East"      3       514
210     "East"      9       514
214.95  "East"      6       559
216.9   "East"      11      514
219.95  "East"      6       559
245     "East"      11      559
309     "East"      5       716
329.9   "East"      11      716
141.5   "North"     2       378
165     "North"     6       383
209.95  "North"     4       559
205     "North"     2       514
222.9   "North"     3       514
250     "North"     6       716
259     "North"     4       716
265     "North"     1       884
```

What I want to figure out is how I can use a do-end loop to create four numerical variables, NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST.  I want to set these to 0 or 1 to indicate whether the observation belongs in the building.  Since the building information is stored in our indicator variables I will drop the variable "Building" in my original dataset.  Here's my attempt at this:

```
proc import out=riverplace datafile=”C:\RiverPlace-JulyReport-2007.txt”
   dbms=txt REPLACE
   sheet=”auto”
   getnames=yes
run;
data riverplace3
   set riverplace (drop=Building)
   do Building=’North’, ‘South’, ‘East’, ‘West’;
   if Building=North then NORTH=1
   else Building=0
end;
proc print data=riverplace3
    title=“Indicator Variables Added”;
run;
```

Is my logic correct, especially in the part where I run the do-end loop?  I'm not so sure because for some reason its not running on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

SAS will evaluate logical expressions as 0 (false) or 1 (true).  You can use this to make your data step simpler.

```
data riverplace3;
  set riverplace;
  NORTH = Building='North';
  SOUTH = Building='South';
  EAST  = Building='East';
  WEST  = Building='West';
  drop building;
run;
```

You might need to watch out for the case of the values in `BUILDING` or even whether those quotes that you listed in your sample data made it into the value of your variable.  You might want to not drop BUILDING and do a quick `PROC FREQ` to make sure the values got translated properly.

```
proc freq data=riverplace3 ;
  tables building*north*south*east*west / list missing;
run;
```

Comment: I should I have learnt a "new-way-to-do-the-same-thing" and this answer is very good. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a do loop variable with the same name as a variable in your dataset. How would SAS know which building to refer to? Also, with the drop on your input data set, your variable is being dropped before you process it. And you're missing semi colon in multiple places again! I doubt your proc import code even works properly without the semicolons.

I think what you may want instead is a loop over an array to test the values and assign it a 1/0 otherwise.

```
data riverplace3;
set riverplace;

*Set up an array for directions;
array dir(4) North South East West;
*Set up loop for array;
do i=1 to 4;
*Check if name of building matches name of variable - using vname function;
if upper(Building)=upper(vname(dir(i))) then dir(i)=1;
Else dir(i)=0;
end;

run;
```

Comment: So if I want to drop Building, then I would still place (drop=Building) right after the second line of the above code, right?

Comment: No. Either add as line if code or in first line of code.

Comment: You cannot drop building using a `DROP=` dataset option on the `SET` statement because that means that it never makes it into the data step to be tested.  You can either drop it using a `DROP` statement in the data step or by using a `DROP=` dataset option on the dataset named in the `DATA` statement.

Comment: I dont think the terminology is do-end loop. I think its just a do loop. All do loops require an END, do-while, do-until and even a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make the final code simple and one which you can debug easily the below code might help,

```
data want;
  set have;
  length North South East West 3. NoDirection $10;
  North=0; South=0; East=0; West=0; * Initialize Values;
  select(upcase(Building)); * Use the Select-When clause;
    when ("NORTH") North=1;
    when ("SOUTH") South=1;
    when ("EAST")  East=1;
    when ("WEST")  West=1;
    otherwise NoDirection="NO DATA"; * Additional Variable NoDirection for Data Related errors;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Nice code, but I sort of wanted to do see how this is done with the do-end loop...